# Using OCaml to output a simple multiplication table

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to create a simple function that can write output to a file, say file.txt. The output is a multiplication table (as seen below).

Example of the multiplication table if the function argument is 5:
[image: Example of the multiplication table if the function argument is 5]

The problem is that OCaml just hangs when I run the code (probably because of an infinite recursion?). I keep looking through the logic and it seems okay..

```
(*n is the row counter and n2 is the column counter*)
let rec row ch x n =
    let rec column ch x n n2 =
        (*If column counter reaches limit then stop here*)
        if (n2 = x+1)
        then ()
        else
            output_string ch (string_of_int (n2*n));
            output_char ch '\t';
            column ch x n (n2+1)
    in
        column ch x n 1;

        (*If row counter reaches limit then stop here*)
        if n = x+1
        then ()
        else
            output_char ch '\n';
            row ch x (n+1);;
```

Later I call row in table function like this:

```
let rec table file x =
    let ch = open_out file in
        row ch x 1;
        close_out ch;;
```

When I run `table "foo" 5`, it just hangs. Also, in the future, how can I better handle errors like this? Any recommended debugging options for OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two cases of the same problem: the `else` part of `if/then/else` controls just one expression but you're expecting it to control several expressions.

In the first case, the `else` is just controlling the `output_string`. This means that the rest of the `column` function is going to be executed in all cases. This is, in fact, an infinite recursion.

In the second case the `else` just controls the `output_char`. Again, this gives you an infinite recursion.

You can fix this by adding `begin/end` here:

```
begin
output_string ch (string_of_int (n2*n));
output_char ch '\t';
column ch x n (n2+1)
end
```

And here:

```
begin
output_char ch '\n'; row ch x (n+1)
end
```

After I make these changes, the code works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Worked for me too. Does else only control the print expression immediately after it because of the semicolon operator? (the operator, if I am remembering correctly, throws away the expression on its left)

Comment: Yes, another way to look at it is that `then` and `else` have higher precedence than `;`. You can combine multiple expressions other ways that don't require the `begin/end`.